# How to Disable Attribute on Action When Applied at Controller Level?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, annotations

I have the following controller:

```
[NoCache]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin,useradmin")]
    public ActionResult GetUserEntitlementReport(int? userId = null)
    {
        var byteArray = GenerateUserEntitlementReportWorkbook(allResults);

        return File(byteArray,
                System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,
                "UserEntitlementReport.xls");
    }
}

public class NoCache : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response; 
        response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the controller is decorated with the `[NoCache]` attribute.

Is there any way to prevent this attribute from being applied to the `GetUserEntitlementReport` action?

I know I can remove the attribute at the controller level but that is not my favorite solution because the controller contains many other actions and i don't want to have to apply the attribute to each action independently.

Comment: I believe you would just have to apply [NoCache] to the individual methods instead of applying it to the whole class. That would lead to manually repeating the attribute for all methods, but will let you run GetUserEntitlementReport without it.

Comment: @amhed - I know that option is available but I'm trying to find an alternative solution (see last paragraph in question description).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a new Attribute which can be used on individual Actions to opt out of the NoCache specified at the controller level.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class |
                AttributeTargets.Method,
                AllowMultiple = false,
                Inherited = true)]
public sealed class AllowCache : Attribute { }
```

Mark any Actions where you want to allow caching with `[AllowCache]`

Then in the code for your `NoCacheAttribute` only disable caching if the `AllowCache` attribute is not present

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        var actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        bool allowCaching = actionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowCache), true) ||
            actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowCache), true);

        if(!allowCaching)
        {
            //disable caching.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a attribute you can apply on action.
That is [OverrideActionFilters].

```
[NoCache]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin,useradmin")]
    [OverrideActionFilters]
    public ActionResult GetUserEntitlementReport(int? userId = null)
    {
        var byteArray = GenerateUserEntitlementReportWorkbook(allResults);

        return File(byteArray,
                System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,
                "UserEntitlementReport.xls");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by [implementing and registering a custom filter provider](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html). As a starting point, I would derive from [FilterAttributeFilterProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattributefilterprovider%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and override GetFilters to remove the NoCache attribute when appropriate.